# ContentTemplate Binding question

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have DataGrid control from WPF Toolkit in my app. I need replace default TextBlock used for cells with tuned TextBlock. XAML-code looks something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <tk:DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource cellStyle}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Id"
                Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <tk:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Product"
                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </tk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

After TextBlock replacement all data binding is lost and all the cells are empty. Adding property Text="{Binding}" to the new TextBlock doesn't help. In this case all the cells contain name of type DataGridTestApp.Product. What will be the right binding expression for TextBlock?

P.S. Just in case: code for MainWindowViewModel

```
internal sealed class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
        {
            new Product(1, "ProductName1"),
            new Product(2, "ProductName2"),
            new Product(3, "ProductName3"),
            new Product(4, "ProductName4"),
            new Product(5, "ProductName5"),
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _products;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code to the Toolkit you will find the existing style for the datagrid cell (it uses a content presenter to display the column)

```
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static dg:DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

To get your yellow background I would just replace

```
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
```

with

```
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
```

If you are desperate to override the TextBlock inside then use the above template but add this just inside the Border

```
<Border.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
  </Style>
</Border.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it was simplified example of my problem. Actually I need TextBlock with Margin property set to "0,5". I can set Margin property for DataGridCell but it is not the same for me. Row selection look will differ.

Comment: Won't setting the contentpresenters padding/margin have the same effect?

Comment: In this case selection will not include margin/padding. And there will be big gaps between adjancent selections. The problem solved if Margin property of TextBlock is set.

Comment: I finally came to ContentPresenter solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBlock's data context is a Product. If it's the name of the product you want to display, then use this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="cellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Unfortunately, if you override the template, you lose any bindings set up in the DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: In case of Text="{Binding Name}" all the cells will contain the name of products, but cell content should depend on column. For the first column all cells should display product id, for second - product name. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh I see. I think like Bob Vale says, you should use a ContentPresenter.